# Open directory containing file during counsel-file-jump

Tags: files, find-file, ivy

I use `counsel-file-jump` to search files recursively. I would like to open the directory that contains a particular file candidate. I can execute `counsel-dired` after I open the file, which allows me to open the directory which contains the file. I would like to jump straight to this directory without first opening the file.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: AFAIK, `counsel-file-jump` does not currently support this OOTB. For now, you could `M-i` (`ivy-insert-current`) to yank the selected candidate into the search string, edit the yanked string to remove the non-directory part, and then `C-M-j` (`ivy-immediate-done`) to visit the resulting directory. However, I suggest you submit a feature request at https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues to add an action to `counsel-file-jump` to do this automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a new *Ivy action* that opens the directory of a file name selection.  It can be done with:

```el
(defun my/ivy-open-dir-action (x)
  (interactive)
  (dired (or (file-name-directory x)
             default-directory)))

(ivy-add-actions
 #'counsel-file-jump
 '(("d" my/ivy-open-dir-action "open in dired")))
```

To invoke it, you can search normally and then `M-o d` to fire this action.  In case you want to know more about *Ivy actions*, I recommend you take a look in the Ivy docs, specifically under [`(ivy) Actions`](https://oremacs.com/swiper/#actions).

Comment: @Basil this seems to be a useful feature. Could you (or someone else) PR in the swiper repo with this?

Comment: @andrej If no-one beats me to it, sure.

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/pull/2057